# Is there a way to stop downloading an app without restarting the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is there anyway to stop downloading an iphone app without restarting the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pause the download while it's in the "loading" stage by tapping the app icon (tap again to resume), but I couldn't find a way to actually cancel the download.